# Why awx don't see pip module?

Tags: centos, ansible-awx

I use AWX 8.0.0.0. Have job on my SCM, that job connect to GCP and create instance. When i run this job under console like `ansible-playbook job.yml` its done fine. But when i run it from web UI i get error

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Please install the google-auth library"}` 
So it oblivious mean that i don't have this library. But I install it by
`pip install google-auth` and it work fine when I run it from console. This is my playbook:

```
- name: Create jenkins vm
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    service_account_email: ansible@secret-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    credentials_file: /etc/conf/awx/awx.json
    project_id: geocitizen-app
    machine_type: f1-micro
    machine_name: jenkins-node-1
    image: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/centos-cloud/global/images/centos-7-v20191014
    zone: europe-north1-a
  tasks:
   - name: Launch instances
     gcp_compute_instance:
       auth_kind: serviceaccount
       name: "{{ machine_name }}"
       machine_type: "{{ machine_type }}"
       #service_account_email: "{{ service_account_email }}"
       service_account_file: "{{ credentials_file }}"
       project: "{{ project_id }}"
       zone: "{{ zone }}"
       network_interfaces:
       - network:
         access_configs:
         - name: External NAT
           type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
       disks:
       - auto_delete: 'true'
         boot: 'true'
         initialize_params:
           source_image: "{{ image }}"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I was looking on my host machine. I install AWX via docker so I need to look in my docker container.